# How to get Branch Name in a manually triggered pipeline in Jenkins?

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, cmd

I have a freestyle project in Jenkins which sometimes is triggered manually, and I want to get the branch name or the commit message using the commit hash.

I have found this example but I'm getting an error when I try to use it.
**Error "expecting ')', found ':' "**

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin --contains 29c2b3672b | awk "/a/ {print \$2}"').trim()
```

Thanks to @AVTUNEY I was able to fix the error.

But I have been using this git command and with some commit hash this works well and with some others this doesn't work properly.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape single quotes in `--format`

This will work:

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git for-each-ref --format=\"%(objectname) %(refname:short)\" refs/remotes/origin --contains 29c2b3672b | awk '/a/ {print $2}'").trim()
```

Comment: Why not `--format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)'` single quotes inside double quotes?

Comment: Hi @AVTUNEY, your solution does work but you also have to escape the $2 in the end like this: `awk '/a/ {print \$2}'`. Thank you

Comment: @phd because like that you get an error as I have said in the question above.

Comment: My question was to @AVTUNEY. I don't see a need for escaped double quotes inside double quotes — just use single quotes inside double quotes. Or vice versa.

Comment: Something that doesn't look good with this git command is that I don't get every time the current commit message. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?